# Padding zeros and remove commas, decimals, and dashes in tsql

Tags: t-sql

I have an amount field and a commission field that I need to remove the comma: `,` decimal point: `.` dash: `-` and the percent sign: `%`.

I have tried replicate, format, replace and stuff,

- `right ('000000000')`
- `right('000000000') + rtrim(field), len#)`
- `RTRIM(replicate('0', 9 - len(field)) + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(field as varchar), ',', ''), '.',''), '-', ''))`
- RTRIM(replicate('0', 9 - len(t.Commission_Amount)) + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(t.Commission_Amount as varchar(9)), ',', ''), '.',''), '-', ''))

but I never get the results that I want. When I use replace it replaces the comma, dash, or `%` but cuts the field short and does not pad to the left with zeros. I know it's probably right in front of my face I just need some clarity please.

- `00-126.47` comes out as `0012647`
- `0.00` comes out as `00000000`
- `000126.47` comes out as `00012647`

Comment: always use a length when casting to varchar, such as varchar(50) or something like that.

Comment: same resultRTRIM(replicate('0', 9 - len(field)) + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(cast(field as varchar(9)), ',', ''), '.',''), '-', ''))

Comment: Is the last part your desired output or your current? the output is 7 digits long on the first one, 8 on the second and 9 on the third. It's not really clear what you want to achieve here.

Comment: the field length is 9 but if I remove the .,or % it cuts the field output. the first field is 7 then the other two are 8 in the output above.

Comment: well, this doesn't happen in my answer as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

create sample table

```
DECLARE @Table as table (
    field varchar(15)
)
```

populate sample table

```
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES 
('00-126.47'), 
('0.00'),
('000126.47'),
('00033%2.422')
```

select

```
SELECT  field As before, 
        RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9) + 
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(field, '-', '')
                    , '.', '')
                , ',', '')
            , '%', '')
        , 9) As [After]
FROM @Table
```

results:

```
before          After
--------------- ---------
00-126.47       000012647
0.00            000000000
000126.47       000012647
00033%2.422     000332422
```

Comment: That worked, I only used one part though. I didn't insert into a table. what I did use was this...RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9) + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '-', ''), '.', ''), ',', ''), '%', ''), 9) As [After]

Comment: Of course, that was just for test. If an answer solved your problem you should accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem;

RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 9) + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(field, '-', ''), '.', ''), ',', ''), '%', ''), 9) As [After]